# may as well vs. may well

Tags: modal-verbs

I am a student learning English.
I know the meanings of "may as well" and "may well", but quite confusing. To understand the meaning, I need some time.
The other day I posted a question how I can distinguish them without confusing, but people who are non-native speakers like me said "I wish I would tell them easily".
How do native speakers tell them without confusing? Just naturally pick up? Or you have your own knack?

Comment: Could you explain what is confusing? [Here is an example explanation](https://www.usingenglish.com/forum/threads/may-well-vs-may-as-well.163890/), is there anything confusing in it?

Comment: The same way that we distinguish any other pair of words or phrases that might have some sounds in common but are different: we just recognise them as different. I know this is probably not a helpful response, but it's reality. There is no point in asking native speakers how they remember the difference between things that they don't need to remember: they just know.

Answer (score 2):

If you ***may well*** do X, it's ***likely*** that you will do X (***well*** is an *intensifier* for ***may***).

We often say you ***may as well*** do X in contexts where the alternatives are to do X or to do Y. The "literal" meaning is that *doing X is just as useful as doing Y*, but there's often an implication that X is an easier or otherwise more attractive option (it's also often implied that neither X nor Y will achieve much).

Sometimes there's no contextually obvious alternative Y to *I may as well do X,* but it's always there *somehow*. The "implicit" alternative is often equivalent to *do nothing*, or *keep doing what you're currently doing.* Both of which apply if, for example, a guest at your party says *This is boring. I may as well go home*.

Comment: Thank you. "Well" is an intensifier in "may well", which helps me understand the meaning.